# Flutter Error: type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I have updated the flutter to 2.8.1 and i dont have any idea as how to solve this

```
factory SubjectAnalysis.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      SubjectAnalysis(
        subjectAnalysis: List<List<SubjectAnalysisElement>>.from((
            json['Subject Analysis'].map((dynamic x) =>
                List<SubjectAnalysisElement>.from(
                    ( x.map((dynamic x) => SubjectAnalysisElement.fromJson(x as Map<String, dynamic>)))as List<dynamic>))as List<dynamic>)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know which of both casts you have to remove… try to remove both

```
as List<dynamic>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code. This is what I understand from the info you have provided.

```
factory SubjectAnalysis.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      SubjectAnalysis(
        subjectAnalysis: List<List<SubjectAnalysisElement>>.from((
            json['Subject Analysis'].map((dynamic x) =>
                List<SubjectAnalysisElement>.from(
                    ( x.map((dynamic x) => SubjectAnalysisElement.fromJson(x as Map<String, dynamic>)))as List<dynamic>))as MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and tried most of the suggested solutions, and I wasn't able to solve the issue, until I did the following:

```
users = (response.data).map<User>((i) => User.fromJson(i)).toList();
```

Just add the data type inside map(), which will cast the data type from List into the data type of your model (a user in this case).

I hope someone will find this useful.